# Sending request back from POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to implement a payment provider (AdYen) into my application. When a payment is done then AdYen will send me a notification by a HTTP POST request to an URL that i supplied in the backoffice. For example:

http://myhost.com/Payment/FinishPayment/

FinishPayment is an Action method in the Payment controller. The call does end up in that method, but AdYen gives me the following error:

> The required string "[accepted]" is not in all the results

Somehow i have to return the string "[accepted]" in a "notificationResponse". But how?

I saw a PHP example which just this:

```
function FinishPayment( ) // function is called by AdYen
{
    // Do stuff...

    return array("notificationResponse" => "[accepted]");
}
```

Anyone any idea how i can send a response back in C#.NET MVC3 ??

Comment: Page 25 of the [integration manual](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:fHylPYHsG3cJ:attachment-c02.memonic.ch/p/290d76e5-2907-4458-a479-a90022267bac/08c9f78b-ce2a-4c7e-bdf6-6f1622f6754c/ef4adb890a/IntegrationManual.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShU_e3kGcTW-aIcwmAIElEdVMPnBhqVldmVEye_240rrSo8oWB6rHLugVU_7zoDKpn1D1D2YdLBK5ZnHakEo68F__kFwJIQ9rC7xjButQNIVGXLD6xo5hiw-W3MMTbGm39-8Xm0&sig=AHIEtbSW6PHdaWbenV6qQ-_Sqe6m7k0CoA) explains it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, but that's SOAP. I'm not using SOAP anywhere in my application so i'd like to avoid that if possible. There must be some way to just send a request to a URL like: http://adyen...com/Notify?response=[accepted]

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there must be a way to do that. I don't see any suggestion in the documentation that they support something other than SOAP.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I was actually hoping that it was possible.. Since you can choose between POST or SOAP when sending out a payment. Guess i have no other choice now. :-( --- I just have no idea how this SOAP / WSDL url stuff works and how to actually send the request (and to what url... Hope i can find some useful info which can take me in the right direction..

Answer (score 2):

This is rather old but as I'm currently working with it, maybe it could help anyone in the future

Choosing HTTP POST instead of SOAP will cause Adyen to make a POST for every notification, so in MVC 3 (or 4, or simply ASP .Net), you could create a generic handler to handle these requests, and just make a `context.Response.Write("[accepted]");`. At least in the Test environment, it seems that they accept those responses as good.

By the way, they don't send any signature of the data as POST parameters, but they will authenticate with basic Http authentication through Authorization Header, if you configure an user and a password, in order to verify the request in your server.